# Would like to convert my powered mixer to a power amp

Tags: mixer

I have a older Yamaha EMX-660 Mono Powered Mixer with 6 channels, our band has expanded with vocals and percussion. To support the additional instruments I've added a 6 XLR input analog mixer (stereo) and send both output channels to the dual line inputs of one the powered mixer channels with the preamp section set to center. It seems to work OK, but I would like to simplify my setup by going to a single  channel (8 XLR inputs) with internal digital reverb and send to three channels on the powered mixer (the main outs (R & L) and monitor out). 
The EMX-660 is 300w per channel and works great so I hate to replace it with a power amp at this time, but it is a hassle trying to control sound on two systems. I'm not technical enough to understand how the 6 channels on the EMX work and if sending a 16 channel signal into two channels would harm the power mixer. I'm thinking this would be OK and would basically just use the 3 channels set at neutral and the output volume and EQ.
The powered mixer works great for small events but is limited for full band gigs. I'll appreciate any information or suggestions.

Analog Mixer I'm looking at: (8 XLR with 4 stereo line inputs)
(

)

EMX 660 manual: (https://usa.yamaha.com/files/download/other_assets/3/318553/EMX660E.pdf)

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. If you are sending in to a 2 channel mixer, then you are only sending 2 channels, not 16. If your question is about whether the power amp can take the signal you plan to send it, then you'll need to read the manual to see what output power your mixer has, and what input your amp is rated to.

Comment: @DoktorMayhem - I don't understand how the 'output power' of a mixer is related to the 'input rating' of an amp. I'd have thought any mixer will plug into any power amp (or mixer amp) and be adjustable enough to work.

Comment: @Tim - agreed, however the OP sounds concerned. I'd rather they checked for line output.

Answer (score 2):

Mixer into mixer is fine. Use the new one, however many channels, into two of the original Yamaha's inputs. Keep the eq flat - or tweak as desired - and regard the new mixer as just another couple of inputs. There *may* be a couple of ports between pre and post on the Yamaha, so if you really wanted, it could be used as just a power amp., and you'd plug the new mixer into the power amp inputs, bypassing the mixer section. either way, it ought to work. It depends how much control you want or need. Once set up, it'll only need a touch of fiddling between gigs. Don't try to use both reverb units though.

Comment: Thanks so much, that was my concern - currently having to manage two mixers with one limited to the single channel monitor and effects controls is a hassle. I'm looking for a way to manage all my sound settings from a single mixer and use my powered mixer solely as a power amp.  One thing I saw on another similar post was concerns for phantom power between mixers.  Something I had not considered since we use the PA for live work with dynamic mics.